# Pasting an array of values over a ListObject (Excel table) destroys the Listobject

Tags: excel, excel-2010, listobject, vba

In one of my worksheets, I have a

```
Private Sub BuggingVba()
```

That **should replace the data in a table with an array of values**

```
    Dim MyTable As ListObject, myData() As Variant
    Set MyTable = Me.ListObjects(1)
    myData = collectMyData ' a function defined somewhere else in my workbook
```

It is probably irrelevant, but before doing so, **I resize** the list object *(I expand line by line because if I do it at once, I overwrite what is below my table instead of schifting it.)*

```
    Dim current As Integer, required As Integer, saldo As Integer
    current = MyTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    required = UBound(sourceData, 1) - LBound(sourceData, 1)
    ' current and required are size of the body, excluding the header

    saldo = required - current

    If required < current Then
        ' reduce size
        Range(DestinBody.Rows(1), DestinBody.Rows(current - required)).Delete xlShiftUp
    Else
        ' expland size
        DestinBody.Rows(1).Copy
        For current = current To required - 1
            DestinBody.Rows(2).Insert xlShiftDown
        Next saldo
    End If
```

If there is any data to insert, **I overwrite the values**

```
    If required Then
        Dim FullTableRange As Range
        Set FullTableRange = MyTable.HeaderRowRange _
            .Resize(1 + required, MyTable.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count)
        FullTableRange.Value = sourceData
    End If
```

**And BAM, my table/ListObject is gone!**  Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried just not overwriting the headers?

Comment: I thought about `MyTable.DataRange = slice(1 + souceData, LBound(sourceData, 1), UBound(sourceData, 1))`, @Rory, but **1.** VBA has no slice function **2.** I have to update my headers too.

Comment: Then it's probably as easy to just add the table back at the end.

Comment: I could but then I should save the sorting and filtering the used applied first and reconstruct it afterwards.

Comment: I corrected it by updating cell by cell now. That works. @Rory, if there comes no better solution, do you think this is worth wile to enter this as a solution, or should I delete the question?

Comment: I would think cell by cell was slower than recreating the table - unless it's a small table? Probably worth leaving it - someone else is bound to run into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we paste over the entire table or clear the contents of the entire table the collateral result is that the table object (`ListObject`) is deleted. That’s the reason the code works when the data is changed row by row.

However, there is no need to do it row by row, not even the insertion of new rows if we work with the properties of the `ListObject` as demonstrated in the code below.

In these procedures we assumed that the *"Target"* `Table` and the *“New Data”* are, in the same `workbook` holding the code, located at worksheets `1` and `2` respectively:

As we will work with the `HeaderRowRange` and the `DataBodyRange` of the `ListObject` then we need to obtain the “New Data” to replace the data in the table in the same manner. The code below will generate two arrays with the Header and Body Arrays.

```
Sub Dta_Array_Set(vDtaHdr() As Variant, vDtaBdy() As Variant)
Dim vArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sht(1)").Range("DATA") 'Change as required
        vArray = .Rows(1)
        vDtaHdr = vArray
        vArray = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
        vDtaBdy = vArray
    End With
End Sub
```

Then use this code to replace the data in the table with the *"New Data"*

```
Private Sub ListObject_ReplaceData()
Dim MyTable As ListObject
Dim vDtaHdr() As Variant, vDtaBdy() As Variant
Dim lRowsAdj As Long

    Set MyTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1) 'Change as required

    Call Data_Array_Set(vDtaHdr, vDtaBdy)

    With MyTable.DataBodyRange
        Rem Get Number of Rows to Adjust
        lRowsAdj = 1 + UBound(vDtaBdy, 1) - LBound(vDtaBdy, 1) - .Rows.Count

        Rem Resize ListObject
        If lRowsAdj < 0 Then
            Rem Delete Rows
            .Rows(1).Resize(Abs(lRowsAdj)).Delete xlShiftUp

        ElseIf lRowsAdj > 0 Then
            Rem Insert Rows
            .Rows(1).Resize(lRowsAdj).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If: End With

    Rem Overwrite Table with New Data
    MyTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = vDtaHdr
    MyTable.DataBodyRange.Value = vDtaBdy

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I can set `MyTable.DataBodyRange.Value` to something. This would have loved my problem if you were in time. **But** I calculate the values in memory, not in another spreadsheet because changing values of thousands of cells takes too long, even with `ScreenUpdating = False` **and** I tried tomething like `.Rows(1).Resize(lRowsAdj).Insert Shift:=xlDown` but that messed up my sheet. **and** correct your typo: `Dta_ArraySet` is not `Dta_Array_Set`

Answer (score -1):

Old post, but the way I paste over a listobject table is to delete the databodyrange, set a range to the array size and then set the range to the array.  Similar to the solution provided above, but doesn't require resizing the table.

```
'Delete the rows in the table
    If lo.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        lo.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

'Assign the range to the array size then assign the array values to the range
    Set rTarget = wsTemplate.Range("A2:K" & UBound(arrTarget) + 1)
    rTarget = arrTarget
```

Comment: Would you mind _either_ use the same name for objects I used _or_ clearly describe them _or_ include more code, _so that_ we understand you with less effort? My down-vote might become an upvote.